# Sample size calculation for safety trial

Tags: sample-size, sample

I need to know how to calculate the sample size for a safety trial of a combination of two drugs VS placebo.

I have the proportions of event (AEs) for each drug:

Drug A p1 = 0.12
Drug B p2 = 0.09

I don't know how to calculate the sample size without data of their combination.

Comment: If you know the proportions already, why run a trial? What exactly are you trying to show?

Comment: The two proportions indicated are referred to single drug (AEs) we want to use a combination of these drugs for comparing the combination safety to the placebo. Our problem it is to calculate the sample size without the proportion data of the drug combination.